# Grails Doc Tags

Tags: html, css, grails

Information on the grails documentation tool is sparse.

I could only find this small section in [grails.org](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#docengine)

The authors also mention that gdoc tags are similar to Textile or Confluence markup.

But so far, I have been unable to figure out how to simply align an image.

In Confluence: !someImage.png|align=center! should work, yet doesn't for gdocs.

In Textile: %align:right% should add html styles but doesn't work for gdocs either.

Is there anywhere I could find a complete reference for tags that can be used in gdoc files?

EDIT:
I have also tried...

```
!{padding-left: 10em;}image.png! 
!=image.png!
!>image.png!
```

Is there no support for this in grails docs?

Answer (score 0):

Images can be aligned as below

```
//center
!=someImage.png!

// should result
<p><img src="someImage.png" align="center" alt="" /></p>

//right
!>someImage.png!

// should result
<p><img src="someImage.png" align="right" alt="" /></p>
```

Test it in [textile](http://textile.sitemonks.com/).

Here is a set of [syntax definitions for images](http://txstyle.org/doc/14/images). I guess [wiki syntax](https://grails.org/WikiSyntax) has already been referred.

Comment: None of these worked for me !=image.png! displayed as text and !>image.png! displayed a broken image. What version of grails are you using?

Comment: Also found it kinda funny the sample image on that wiki syntax page is broken -_-

Comment: Yes. Looks like an improvement in grails `DocEngine`. This works in the Textile demos. Plus, do you need align center in image or text-align the paragraph wrapping `<img>` to center? Raise an [issue in github](https://github.com/grails/grails-doc/issues?state=open), I can or anybody from Grails team can look into it.

Comment: I believe text-align: center is the default for img center. Ideally I would like to apply custom padding to the image, perhaps with Textile's {padding-left: 10em} format? I may raise an issue soon if there isn't a workaround. Thank you!